# Adding data to Multidimensional Array in while loop

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working on a `GetClicks(win)` function where I need to get data of mouse click position from a Window with pointer win.

I want to save 4-dimensional mouse data into an array. How can I create a multidimensional array in a loop?

**My current code looks like this:**

```
while 1       
    [clicks, x, y, Button] = GetClicks(win) ;
    i = i+1;    
end
```

I just need to add array loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set a maximum amount of clicks `N` you can write your loop the following way:

```
N = 100;
A = zeros(N,4);
for i=1:N       
    [clicks, x, y, Button] = GetClicks(win);
    A(i,1) = clicks;
    A(i,2) = x;
    A(i,3) = y;
    A(i,4) = Button;
end
```

I do not know in which format `clicks x y Button` are returned. I have supposed they are scalars. If that's not the case please write a reply to update the solution.